# Perspective doesn't work on mozilla firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, parallax, mozilla, prefixes

I have got tricky question. Maybe somebody knows why the perspective doesn't work on firefox, but it works properly on chrome for example.

Here is some css I have used:

```
@mixin perspective-parallax{
-webkit-perspective: 100px;
-moz-perspective: 100px;
perspective: 100px;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style:  preserve-3d;
-ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
```

}

```
@mixin parralax-item{
@include flex;
flex: 1 0 auto;
position: relative;
height: 600px;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
-ms-transform:  translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
-moz-transform:  translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
z-index: -1;
```

}

```
.top-slider{
text-align: center;
@include perspective-parallax;
height: 600px;
.bx-slider {
    .main-slide-1{
        background: url('../img/bulb-2587637_1920.jpg') top center no-repeat fixed;
        @include main-slide;
        @include parralax-item;
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: I think `transform-style: preserve-3d;` should be define on the transformed element not the parent

Comment: I have already tried it and doesn;t work as well.

Comment: can you create a working code that we can test?

Comment: Yes, I have done this:https://codepen.io/blosiu1212/pen/mKGmPa

Comment: Once I implemented it, and it was working in firefox too.

Comment: Can you send the code please? Or write what to do?